# In android, want to stop automatic screen tracking in Firebase and make it custom

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to disable auto screen_view event and want to register some of screens only using setCurrentScreen function.

For that what I did is, In Manifest file set below code to disable firebase auto data collection

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

after that I started implement below code to register screen in activity.

```
firebaseanalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

firebaseanalytics.setCurrentScreen(this,"Screen1","Screen1");

firebaseanalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
```

I got the below log in logcat.

```
screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)="XXXX_Screen_Name", firebase_previous_id(_pi)=5346877954560110742, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Screen1, firebase_screen_id(_si)=5346877954560110743, firebase_screen(_sn)=Screen1}].
```

After 24 Hour i checked Firebase console but I was not able to see that screens name which i register manually in screen_view event.

Please help me.
Thanks